# How to Active Loop Tab PHP

Tags: php, html, css, loops, tabs

I don't know what to do loop and active tab on php.Active only one tab at a time.

My tab

[image]

```
<div class="container content">
    <div class="row tab-v3">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <?php do { ?>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li><a href="#<?php echo $row_menulist['mlname']; ?>" data-toggle="tab"><i></i><?php echo $row_menulist['mlname']; ?></a></li>
            </ul>
          <?php } while ($row_menulist = mysql_fetch_assoc($menulist)); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="<?php echo $row_menulist['mlname']; ?>">
                  <?php do { ?>
                    <h4><?php echo $row_info['mlname']; ?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo $row_info['detail']; ?></p>
                  <?php } while ($row_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($info)); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you means active only one tab at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove active class,i assume that change in loop not affect in design.

```
<div class="container content">
        <div class="row tab-v3">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <?php do { ?>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li><a href="#<?php echo $row_menulist['mlname']; ?>" data-toggle="tab"><i></i><?php echo $row_menulist['mlname']; ?></a></li>
                </ul>
              <?php } while ($row_menulist = mysql_fetch_assoc($menulist)); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <?php $count = 1; do { ?>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade in <?php if($count == '1') { echo 'active'; } ?>" id="<?php echo $row_menulist['mlname']; ?>">

                        <h4><?php echo $row_info['mlname']; ?></h4>
                        <p><?php echo $row_info['detail']; ?></p>

                    </div>
                    <?php $count++; } while ($row_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($info)); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working!

I even use the same logic into a CMS PHP Based (SPIP).

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        <div class="w-100 srvc-tab">
            <ul class="nav nav-tab">
                <?php $count = 1; ?>
                <BOUCLE_getServiceTitle (ARTICLES){id_rubrique=#ID_RUBRIQUE}{par id_article}{tous}>
                <li class="<?php if($count == '1') { echo 'active'; } ?>">
                    <a href="#service-#COMPTEUR_BOUCLE" data-toggle="tab">
                        [(#TITRE)]
                    </a>
                </li>
                <?php $count++; ?>
                </BOUCLE_getServiceTitle>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <div class="w-100 tab-content">
            <?php $count = 1; ?>
            <BOUCLE_getServiceContent (ARTICLES){id_rubrique=#ID_RUBRIQUE}{tous}>
                <div id="service-#COMPTEUR_BOUCLE" class="col-xs-12 tab-pane fade in <?php if($count == '1') { echo 'active'; } ?>">
                    <div class="w-100 mb-15 pb-15">
                        <h3 class="mb-0 text-capitalize fw-600">
                            [(#TITRE)] 
                            <span class="d-inline-block stroke"></span>
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w-100">
                        [(#TEXTE)]
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php $count++; ?>                              
            </BOUCLE_getServiceContent>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```